# Laravel Controller not being invoked

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I have never used Laravel before and am trying to get my first controller working, using Laravel 10.45.1.

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#writing-controllers) says I should put this in my route file. In my case, I put these lines in `/routes/web.php`.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\TestController;
Route::get ('/test', [TestController::class, 'abc']);
```

In `app/Http/Controllers/TestController.php`, I have the following:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct ()
    {
    }

    public function abc ()
    {
        return view ('welcome'):
    }
}
```

I also have a `/public/test/index.php` file, which contains:

```
echo ('in index.php');
```

When I go to the page in my browser, it tells me it is `in index.php`. It never invokes my controller function. If I delete the index file from the public subdirectory, it gives me a 404.

What do I need to do to get it to invoke my controller function when it receives a request for that route?

Comment: *"When I go to the page in my browser"* - What, specifically, does that mean? Are you running a webserver, or are you navigating to `index.php`? Typically, you run `php artisan serve` and navigate to `http://localhost:8000`, which then uses `public/index.php` (not sure why you have `/test` there) to serve your Laravel application. Navigating to `http://localhost:8000/test` will then route your request to `TestController`'s `public function abc()` method, which should then return the contents on `resources/views/welcome.blade.php`.

Comment: @TimLewis Yes, I'm running `php artisan serve` and going to `localhost/test` in my browser. The only reason I put `public/index.php` there was to see if it would respond to it, and it does. But if I remove `public/index.php`, it responds with a 404 error. It seems to have no knowledge of my controller function at all.

Comment: you shouldn't have a folder in the application's public folder with the same name as a route URI ...

Comment: are you using any web server like 'apache' or 'nginx' or 'wamp' or 'xampp'

Comment: @HoseainSanadgol Yes, I am using nginx.

Answer (score 0):

@Zephyrus if u developed on local:
when u run `php artisan serve` default url path to ur site is

```
http://localhost:8000
```

but u say u are going to

```
http://localhost/test
```

i thin this is problem and when u go to 'localhost' the nginx was rsponsed on port '80'!
for see ur website u should search 'localhost' on port '8000'. so just go to 'http://localhost:8000'.

and if you are on server thst i think this is not correct! than u should fix ur config server file on server!

Answer (score -1):

You need to create the "welcome" view.

Create the view in

resources >> views >> welcome.blade.php

Whatever you put in that file, when you visit the /test route, your function "abc" will be executed.

Comment: The welcome view came with the default installation, so it was already there before I started changing anything, and it works for my "/" route.

Comment: In your function abc, you are still calling that same view, so it will go to that same file. If you want to use a different file, you need to create the blade file in resources >> views and that file you can then reference in your function abc.

Comment: Suppose you want to show a form, you can create a file called add-user.blade.php, inside resources >> views. You type your html for the form there. Now, in function abc, you then return view('add-user'); this will now give you your desired output.  Inside resources >> views, you can also create folders and inside the folders you put files. That will make your project more readable.